# Outlook VBA: Script not triggering on email receive when computer is locked

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a VB script running on my outlook session that watches every new email coming in and is triggered when a specific email address and subject are received. It then saves the attachment from that email and triggers an excel macro to run.

When I test this (by sending the email myself from another email address) it works fine. This morning, my computer received the email (but the computer was "locked", windows 7), but the script wasn't triggered. I know the vba should be working in the background, even when the computer is "locked", so i'm confused why this script didn't trigger.

Does my VBA script not constantly run in the background, despite whether the computer is locked or not?

Here's the code:

> Trigger macro "go" when receiving email from example@example.com AND subject = Today

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    'This sub catches every new email (or collection of emails)
    Dim intMsgIDStart As Integer, intMsgIDEnd As Integer
    Dim strMailItemID As String
    Dim cont As Boolean

    intMsgIDStart = 1
    intMsgIDEnd = InStr(intMsgIDStart, EntryIDCollection, ",")

    cont = True
    Do
        If (intMsgIDEnd > 0) Then
            strMailItemID = Strings.Mid(EntryIDCollection, intMsgIDStart, (intMsgIDEnd - intMsgIDStart))
        Else
            strMailItemID = EntryIDCollection
        End If
        cont = handleMessage(strMailItemID)
        intMsgIDStart = intMsgIDEnd + 1
        intMsgIDEnd = InStr(intMsgIDStart, EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Loop While intMsgIDEnd <> 0 And cont

End Sub

Public Function handleMessage(strMailItemID As String)
    ' This function takes an email ID and determines whether it's our pricing sheet email.
    ' If so, it'll save it to the folder with a common name, pricing.xls
    ' Finally, it will call on runExcelMacro()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim path As String
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = True
    Set mailItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strMailItemID)
    If (mailItem.SenderEmailAddress = "example@example.com" And Strings.Mid(mailItem.Subject, 1, 5) = "Today") Then

        path = "C:\path\Pricing.xls"
        mailItem.Attachments.item(1).SaveAsFile path
        Call runExcelMacro("C:\path\Auto.xlsm", "go")
        result = False
    End If
    handleMessage = result
End Function

Public Function runExcelMacro(path As String, macroName As String)
    'This function starts a macro
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open (path)
    'xl.Visible = False
    xl.Run macroName

    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    xl.Quit

    Set xl = Nothing

End Function
```

Maybe I need to use a different setting to have VBA always run in the background?

Thanks, and apologies that my question isn't as well defined as I would like - I'm just not even sure what is wrong!

Cheers,

Zac

Comment: There is a bug here "On Error Resume Next" without On Error GoTo 0 Remove it and with luck you will get dialog box with an error message.

Answer (score 1):

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. Here is what MSDN states the for the event:

> But for users with an Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode or Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only for messages that arrive at the server after Outlook has started. The event will not fire for messages that are synchronized in Cached Exchange Mode immediately after Outlook starts, nor for messages that are already on the server when Outlook starts in non-Cached Exchange Mode.
>
> The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item. **Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.**

Anyway, I'd suggest creating a rule instead. Then you can assign a VBA sub to a rule. The VBA sub should look like the following one:

```
public sub TEST(mail as MailItem)
   ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

where the mail object represents the incoming Outlook item. As you may see there is no need to get the incoming mail item programmatically by using the GetItemFromId method.

```
path = "C:\path\Pricing.xls"
```

Also I'd recommend choosing another drive for saving attachments. In recent OS the C: drive requires admin privileges for writing.

Comment: Thanks man for answering! I wonder if the cached exchange mode has something to do with this. How would a rule work in this use case? I'm waiting for a specific email to come in, perhaps have that message filter into a special folder which the vb script is there watching? I'm not sure I understand how a rule would be used here.